# How to find and replace data in a column via Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, migration

I have a column called "meta" in a table called "Notifications". The data in the column looks something like this:

```
---
:full_name: Dude
:user_id: 1
:update_id: 10
:update_type: want
:update_name: Some name here
```

and I want it to be changed to something like this:

```
---
:full_name: Dude
:user_id: 1
:post_id: 10
:post_type: want
:post_name: Some name here
```

What would a migration to achieve this look like?

Comment: How do you access the meta column? Is it just plain string or serialized in any way?

Comment: @christian.buggle Just a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def up 
  execute "update notifications set meta = replace(meta, 'update', 'post')"
end
```

I'm not entirely sure about the double quotes / single quotes, as I've seen both sometimes working sometimes failing even within different versions of the same SQL engine.

It is usually a good idea to use SQL to migrate data, as your ruby models might change over time and render your migration unusable, e.g. due to altered validation constraints. The same in ruby would look like

```
def up
  Notification.find_each{ | n | n.update_attribute(:meta, n.meta.gsub('update','post')) }
end
```

Comment: Take care, if your "Some Name here" contains the term 'update', you might want to restrict your substitution to a regex ruling that out.

Comment: This is small, but it's probably a `Notification` class, rather than `Notifications`.